# Sql datareader already associated high frequency polling

Tags: c#, mysql

I've a block of code that gets executed every ~ 0.25 seconds. It works fine for around the first ten iterations until it crashes with an "Datareader already associated with this connection" error, despite the fact that I am closing the data reader being used every time. Could the speed of the requests be causing this? I slowed it down to executing every 1.5 seconds and it still happened. This connection is used nowhere else bar this block so I'm not sure why its happening.

```
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryString, connection);
            var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dataReader);
            dataReader.Close();
            dataReader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: What triggers the timer? eg. does it involve different threads? Also, try to use the disposable pattern.

Comment: First, use `using(...){...}` statements to do the Disposing. And add one for the connection as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, two operations run concurrently at some point. Since you're using the same connection for each, you run into a concurrency issue - by default, one connection only supports a single open cursor. All that needs to happen is the DB query taking longer than the timer interval.

Add synchronization to ensure two requests don't run at the same time - if there's already a request pending, just return immediately.

Also, make sure to use `using` and `try`...`finally` appropriately - it's possible that an exception prevents the `dataReader.Dispose()` from running, which will keep the connection unable to open any new cursors until the reader is disposed of by the GC and finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different connection for the datareader and ExecuteNonQuery